# Drawing using Layers technique in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a different collection which I draw on image, but it slow down my GUI, I want to use layer technique so that I can deal all the collection separately, kindly give me some direction so that I can do it.

Comment: You are going to have to add some additional information about what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually I want to use the layers technique, so that all the collection deal separately in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this [Code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/BufferDrawing.aspx) which discusses a method for drawing using layers. I'm not totally sure that this is what you want, but it involves a layer painting technique.

Basically you have one `Image` that you paint on another, in effect making the changes bubble up to the top.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help. It´s a interesting implementation of an On Screen Display (OSD):
Here is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12597/OSD-window-with-animation-effect-in-C)